# Can we change the url in IOS Safari browser's native sharing buttons(Twitter and Facebook)?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, safari, sharing

We have website with Desktop & Mobile version.

Mobile : m.example.com

Desktop : www.example.com

Ref image : 
[image]

When I open **m.example.com** from IOS safari browser and share url via Twitter or Facebook,
Then shared url will be : m.example.com

**BUT**

I want to share desktop Url (www.example.com), when user share url from mobile version too from safari's native sharing buttons.

is this possible?

Comment: Seeing as this is an interesting question and hasn't been answered I will provide my thoughts on it, I have no idea wether any of this will actually work, just some ideas to maybe think about: perhaps using .htaccess? If you used mod_rewrite to display the URL m.example.com as just example.com would safari share it as that?      Or how about your own social sharing buttons? Alternatively, could you just have them share the m. link and then if the user is on desktop have the page redirect them to the regular site?      (Although I'm assuming you are already doing something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into creating canonical urls to your content. Using open graph meta tags you should be able to set the correct url to share:

```
<link rel=”canonical” href=”http://www.yourdomain.com/page-1″ >
<meta property=”og:url” content=”http://www.yourdomain.com/page-1” />
```

you will likely want to include some more meta tags to fill out the data needed for twitter cards.

references:

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?rd=1